# Miller Rabins Primality Test - Explain it to a math dummy

Tags: group-theory, prime-numbers

How would you explain the miller rabin primality test to someone not understanding fermats little theorem or group theory?

Especially: What is the basic idea of the isComposite(a,n) algorithm (the one that writes $n$ as $n-1 = 2^r \cdot u$?

Are we trying to proof that our potential prime number $n$ is a composition of $a$?

Answer (score 1):

The Miller-Rabin test is a probabilistic test for checking whether or not a given number is prime. It is probabilistic in the sense that its output is *"the input is a prime with high probability"*. The test is based on some theorems about how particular residues of powers of some divisor of your input behave. If there is a number $a$ that violates this property, then you can be sure that your input is not a prime. But if this particular $a$ satisfies the criterion, you can pick another one and repeat the verification. If after many steps, none of the randomly chosen $a$'s notices that your input is not a prime, then you can be sure with some probability (depending on how many repetitions you made) that the input is a prime.